# Making ROC curves with results from cross_validate?

Tags: matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, roc

I am running 5 fold cross validation with a random forest as such:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=8, max_features=6)

cv_results = cross_validate(forest, X, y, cv=5, scoring=scoring)
```

However, I want to plot the ROC curves for the 5 outputs on one graph. The documentation only provides an example to plot the roc curve with cross validation when specifically using StratifiedKFold cross validation (see documentation here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc_crossval.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-roc-crossval-py)

I tried tweeking the code to make it work for cross_validate but to no avail.

How do I make a ROC curve with the 5 results from the cross_validate output being plotted on a single graph?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't cross post questions... https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/477667/building-roc-curves-with-cross-validate

Comment: What are you using for `scoring`?

Answer (score 0):

`cross_validate` is a **Model validation** tool rather than a **splitter class**. You need to choose the [splitter class](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.model_selection) which is right for you. You are probably after [`KFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold). Something like this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
cv = KFold(n_splits=5)
```

Comment: So you mean to say the results generated by using cross_validate cannot be plotted as a Roc_auc graph? I say this because I want to visualize the results created by running cross_validate. If I run a splitter class with random forest and plot the roc_auc results it will not match the results I got with cross_validate.  Is this just something i must accept? Thanks for helping me btw.

Comment: In the link you provided they use `StratifiedKFold`, you said you want to make it work for "5 fold cross validation" instead for stratified K fold cross validation. `StratifiedKFold` is a splitter class and you will need to replace with the splitter class for K fold cross validation which is `KFold`.

Comment: If I run: cv_results = cross_validate(forest, X, y, cv=5, scoring=scoring) one of the scoring metrics I defined is roc_auc. All I want to do is plot those 5 different roc_auc scores on the same graph. You mention this is not possible when using cross_validate becasue cross_validate is model validation tool rather than a splitting tool. But I read that cross_validate automatically uses StratifiedKFold. I just want to take the results from  cv_results = cross_validate(forest, X, y, cv=5, scoring=scoring)  and plot them on a roc_auc graph. Why do I need to use Kfold or a "splitter class"? Thanks